# Understanding batch commands

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

I need to convert some batch commands to C#, but I doubt I understood their functions right.

I converted the batch command

```
set path=%path:~1,-1%
```

into C# like this:

```
path = path.Remove(path.Length - 1);
path = path.Remove(0, 1);
```

But I don't have any idea what to do with (again batch)

```
for /l %%a IN (1,1,5) do (set token=!token:*/=!)
```

I know it's a `for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)` loop, but what for?

Comment: the `set token=!token:*/=!` removes everything up to and including the first `/` from the string in variable `token` and assigns the result to `token`; since this is done in a `for` loop with 5 iterations, the resulting string in `token` is therefore the original string but with everything up to and including the 5th `/` removed;

Comment: ...concerning `set path=`: what's the purpose of removing the first and last character? I've seen that often to remove surrounding `""`; if so, you should chose a more intelligent way to accomplish that to regard the case when there are actually no quotes around...

Comment: I don't understand neither. But did I convert that part of code right?

Comment: It looks correct to me, but I'm not a C# specialist...

Comment: Thank you! Can I email you or contact you somehow? I got a bunch of batch commands I have to convert, so I need help with some of them

Comment: Open cmd.exe. Type `help set` and `help for` at the command prompt. Read. There is detailed information there that answers all of the above.

Comment: As I told I'm not a C# specialist; you might have noticed that I tagged your question with [tag:c#], so more people might be reached; for further _specific_ questions, you could post a new question here; for more general ones (like this one actually in my opinion), superuser.com might be a mire suitable place...